# How to merge two partitions on external hard drive when the "partition" option is greyed out?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk, high-sierra

I have an external hard drive that is connected to my computer by a SATA/eSATA cable. Diskutility recognizes the hard drive as two separate drives as shown in the following two images:

[image: mac_screenshot_1]

[image: mac_screenshot_2]

I can't seem to merge the two partitions (MacBackup & MacBackup2) together because the "Partition" option is greyed out. How do I fix this?

Comment: In Terminal, what it the output of `diskutil list disk2`? Please add the results to the question.

Comment: This can be solved by using the `diskutil mergePartitions ...` command. The whole command depends on additional details like `diskutil list disk2` and `sudo gpt -r show disk2`. The output of the commands should be added to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate the answer by @klanomath this is what you must do step-by-step:

1. get the disk identifier for both disks you want to merge by "diskutil list [disk name]". Choose any of the two disk names, like:

   ```
    diskutil list MacBackup
   ```

This returns something like

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk3
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 MULTIMEDIA              160.0 GB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS TIMEMACHINE             160.0 GB   disk3s2
```

In the IDENTIFIER column, get the disk identifiers for both disks, here: disk3s1 and disk3s2

2. merge the two disk partitions by "mergePartitions  [format] [new disk name][disk identifier 1]  [disk identifier 2]". If you want to use the "MacBackup3", you would then enter:

   ```
   diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ MyMedia disk3s1 disk3s2
   ```

The first disk [disk identifier 1] is the only one that diskutil tries to preserve the data for. If it can't because the disk has no resizable data format, it will give a warning message:

```
The chosen disk does not support resizing.
Do you wish to format instead? (y/N)
```

Caution! If you enter "y", your data on [disk identifier 1] will be deleted. This is the last chance to abort by "N". If you have backed up the data, you can go on with "y" - your disk partitions will be merged.